# Robovm failing to downloading images over https

Tags: java, ios, facebook-graph-api, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to download avatar images from fb using a httpurlconnection. This works well on android. And if I download arbitrary images from a non SSL server it also works on iOS with robovm. If I try to download the Facebook avatars on iOS It fails almost every time. Sometimes it does work (seems random). Should I use a different method for iOS?

I use the following code to download my images (in a separate thread)

```
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoInput(true); 
conn.connect(); 
int length = conn.getContentLength(); 
if(length<=0) return null; 
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
byte[] data = new byte[length]; 
dis.readFully(data); 
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(data, 0, data.length);
```

I run this code in a try/catch/finally block and the code skips to finally (where i disconnect) right after connect(). It throws a IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: unlock of unowned monitor
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: unlock of unowned monitor
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager.syncDownloadPixmapFromURL(ImageManager.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager.access$1(ImageManager.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager$2.run(ImageManager.java)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager.syncDownloadPixmapFromURL(ImageManager.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager.access$1(ImageManager.java)
at bla.helpers.ImageManager$2.run(ImageManager.java)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

Comment: What error do you get or what happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: It hangs on conn.connect. And unless I specify a timeout It just doesn't report/throw anything. (I'm debugging using simple log lines between these code lines, after conn.connect() nothing more is reported)

Comment: Updated my question with some new information

Comment: There are a few pending issues with HTTP, please check your version and the following issue: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/715

Comment: This could be related, although the error is said not to appear in development mode (which I am using for this) and the actual crash occurs in a slightly different part (upgradeToTls vs TrustedCertificateKeyStoreSpi) with a different error (IllegalMonitorStateException vs ExceptionInInitializerError). I will check out the latest snapshot later today.

Comment: This issue is NOT fixed in the latest snapshot, so I am assuming it is something different. I'm going to make a simple sample application to see if I can recreate the error and expose it as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed after reinstalling the roboVM plugin completely. I have no clue as to what the real problem was.